# Use bitmask column or several bit type columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

I am designing a database (sql server integrated into Visual Studio Community 2017) and run into this problem.
I have Tables:

```
Movie
------------
PK MovId,
Title

TorrentMovie
------------
PK TorId,
FK MovId,
TorTitle

User
------------
PK UserId,
Username

UserSpecificTor1
------------
FK UserId,
FK TorId,
Visibility int

UserSpecificTor2
------------
FK UserId,
FK TorId,
NotInteresting bit,
Wrong bit,
Seen bit
```

Visibility could have value of:

```
0x00 Neutral,
0x01 Not interesting,
0x02 Wrong,
0x03 Not interesting & Wrong,
0x04 Seen,
0x05 Not interesting & Seen,
0x06 Wrong & Seen
```

I wonder which approach is better to use: UserSpecificTor1 table or UserSpecificTor2 table? By 'better', I mean the speed of accessing data, complexity of querying data and other advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use columns of [type `bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql), SQL Server will optimize it for storage by itself. No need to add that complexity to the application layer.

> The SQL Server Database Engine optimizes storage of bit columns. If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.

Comment: @Paul. totally agree, even if you want to do some sort of bit masking in your application code you should still use `Bit` for storage. You can always merge them into a `uint` later.